# Standalone JUnit XML report viewer

Tags: gratis, java, xml, reporting, unit-tests

I remember that I used a program for viewing JUnit XML reports two years ago, but I forgot their name and can't google it.

Could you recommend me a simple standalone app (i.e. not IDE) for viewing JUnit XML reports?

Comment: What OS? What pricing?

Comment: Free, for Windows. Thx Nick for asking.

Comment: (as I remember the tool I used before was a single jar file working in any OS)

Answer (score 20):

I got super annoyed with this too so I build a tool myself

https://www.npmjs.com/package/junit-viewer

easy to install and use (requires node but no javascript knowdledge)

Comment: Just used this tool. Works like a charm.

Comment: I updated this a while ago to a more modern (and better) versionhttps://www.npmjs.com/package/xunit-viewer

Answer (score 5):

Try these;

- Generate reports from your build system.

  - Ant JUnitReport: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html and http://earlwillis.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/getting-started-with-junit-reports/
  - Maven surefire-report:report http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-mojo.html
  - Gradle: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html
- Generate reports from your continious integration system

  - Jenkins: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin
- Generate PDF reports; http://junitpdfreport.sourceforge.net/managedcontent/
- Generate reports with history; http://junitth.sourceforge.net/

Alternatively, if you really want to stick with the [limitations] XML reports, you can write a XML stylesheet (aka XSLT), that you can merge with your XML reports to produce almost any output. A quick Google around shows that this has been attempted before;

- http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/directory/studio/trunk/tests/test.integration.core/resources/test-plugins/org.eclipse.test_3.2.0/JUNIT.XSL
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470060/what-xslt-converts-junit-xml-format-to-junit-plain-format
- https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=cr&ei=g7deU-P8O8a2O7KGgdgC#q=xslt+junit

If you want to write you own;

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765388(v=vs.85).aspx

All of the above are FOSS software.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is not an answer. I want a simple standalone app, not build script, not an IDE.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted the same thing for YEARS, I finally found the time to make what I needed and it can be found here: https://github.com/inorton/junit2html

It generates full a full detailed single HTML page that contains all of the test results and captured content with a reasonably easy to browse index.

Comment: That screenshot isn't anything I recognise

Answer (score 2):

I've created a Online JUnit Result Parser/Viewer with just plain Javascript
https://lotterfriends.github.io/online-junit-parser/

Comment: Works great, also for relatively big test report files and can be nicely viewed directly in the browser