# Tool to analyze JUnit/xUnit test results over long periods of time

Tags: unit-tests, log-analysis, junit

Currently I am using the Jenkins JUnit plugin to generate nice graphs/trends for build results. My project doesn't natively produce a JUnit xml file so I manually create one, and the plugin works great.

Trouble is that we're pretty limited on storage on our Jenkins server, so I have to prune our build history relatively frequently and the test history along with it. I'd like to copy the xml files elsewhere where I can store them indefinitely and utilize some other tool to generate similar reports.

So far, the best I have found is UnitTH, but its very old and dated, and I've had to make numerous modification to the code to get it all working. And while I am capable maintaining my fork, or writing something else, web development is not my area of expertise and I'd rather not the spend the time.

I haven't had much success with Google, and I have perused the options presented here: [Standalone JUnit XML report viewer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3666/standalone-junit-xml-report-viewer)
and UnitTH is the closest to what I'm after, but am hoping there is something better.

I have thought about pumping the data into InfluxDB or something, but thats not super friendly for digging into the associated log files.

Any recommendations would be great!